# How to display the greycale image in java after using setRGB?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, grayscale

M working on some image processing program and encountered a problem of displaying the greyscale image. What i did was, i extracted the pixel values using getRGB and then tried to change these pixel values. But after changing these pixel value i'm still getting the same image which was buffered before. My part of code is given below:-

```
  int [] rgbArray=new int[width*height];
  BufferedImage buffer = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
  buffer = ImageIO.read(new File(file));


  //Before changing the pixel values
  buffer.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, rgbArray , 0,width );
  int a = (0xff000000 & rgbArray[0]) >>> 24;
  int r = (0x00ff0000 & rgbArray[0]) >> 16;
  int g = (0x0000ff00 & rgbArray[0]) >> 8;
  int b = (0x000000ff & rgbArray[0]);
  System.out.println("a " + a + " r " + r + " g " + g + " b " + b);
  System.out.println("rgbArray["+0+"] = "+ rgbArray[0]);
  for(int i = 0 ; i<width*height; i++)
   {
     rgbArray[0]=0x808080;  //Changing pixel values to grey
   }
  buffer.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, rgbArray , 0,width);


  //After changing the pixel values
  buffer.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, rgbArray , 0,width );
  a = (0xff000000 & rgbArray[0]) >>> 24;
  r = (0x00ff0000 & rgbArray[0]) >> 16;
  g = (0x0000ff00 & rgbArray[0]) >> 8;
  b = (0x000000ff & rgbArray[0]);
  System.out.println("a " + a + " r " + r + " g " + g + " b " + b);
  System.out.println("rgbArray["+0+"] = "+ rgbArray[0]);
```

Output for the pixel value is coming out to be correct for both original and new pixels but i'm not able to view the new image, it is showing the old i.e original image is shown not the changed image.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You are allocating a large `BufferedImage` in line 2, but then throwing it away and replacing it with the call to `ImageIO.read()`. For the sake of memory, probably don't want to do that.

Comment: yup thax... but how can i display this changed pixel as a image??

Answer (score 1):

```
rgbArray[0]=0x808080;  //Changing pixel values to grey
```

there you are only changig the first pixel to gray. what you probably meant to do:

```
rgbArray[i]=0x808080;  //Changing pixel values to grey
```

which would change every pixel to gray.

// edit:

Of course, then every pixel is exactly the same (grey), which can be done with way less code, e.g.:

```
    Graphics2D g2 = buff.createGraphics();
    g2.setColor(Color.grey);
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, buff.getWidth(), buff.getHeight());
    g2.dispose();
```

If you want a black and white picture instead of a color one, try:

```
    BufferedImageOp op = new ColorConvertOp(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null);
    buffer =  op.filter(buffer, null);
```

Comment: yess sorry it was rgbArray[i]=0x808080; in original code i copied it wrong.. I am getting the correct pixel vales but i'm not getting the correct image displayed...

Comment: @Arizvi that is weird. If I replace 0 with i, load an image, run your code on it and then save it, it is changed (every pixel set to grey). And that is what one would expect (all pixels where assigned a new value so the result should be different from the original...)

Comment: yes its true that every pixel is changed to grey but why it is not being displayed on the image?? I'm still getting the old colored image but not the new grey image on the panel...